# MVC 4 table using DisplayFor and dropdown using DropDownListFor in same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need a dropdown list and a table in my view.

This is my dropdown list:

```
<td>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MP_Name, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) enter code hereViewbag.vbNameMP)
  </td>
```

I want to reference the table items using Html.DisplayFor:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserCode)
    </td>
```

It appears I need @model IEnumerable< for the table, but then I get an error on the drop down list. If I remove IEnumerable from the @model statement the dropdowns work but then the table DisplayFor has an error. How do I accommodate both the dropdown and the table?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `IList<T>` and accommodate both the dropdown and the displayfor inside your `for` loop:

```
@model IList<MyViewModel>

<table>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(
                    x => x[i].MP_Name, 
                    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Viewbag.vbNameMP
                )
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].UserCode)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```